# how to use ASP.NET session in WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-services

how can I use ASP.NET session in WCF? or is there any alternative way to use "ASP.NET Session" like structure in WCF such as data storage?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by using the ASP.NET session in your WCF service? WCF services are typically "per-call" - there's no state stored between two calls and across multiple concurrent callers.

Comment: marc_s: true that is the typical way, but you can definitely have stateful services (at least depending on your binding) (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having a look as ASPCompatibityMode with WCF and you then turn it on and share the session in the service method

Comment: True, but the OP should first make certain that it is the **ASP.NET** session state that he needs. It's possible he just needs a mechanism _like_ ASP.NET Session State.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the ASP.NET session, since you can easily run a WCF service without having the ASP.NET engine fired up, eg. using a netTcpBinding.

There is however session handling native in WCF, where you can specify this on the service contract using the SessionMode parameter on the ServiceContract attribute.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx for more details

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still facing this issue (trying to use a SESSION variable in a .NET Web App consuming a WCF Service). Don't worry about the [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements .......] or adding aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" in the web.config.

After playing around with all that for a while I found out all I had to do was change each [WebMethod] within the _______.ASMX.CS  to [WebMethod (EnableSession=true)].

So change [WebMethod] to [WebMethod (EnableSession=true)]. That's it.

I found out that from http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/04/05/using-session-state-in-a-web-service.aspx

Thanks!

- Bonsai

Comment: That works with Web Methods, but if the WCF service is stand alone, it wont work. http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx covers how to do this in detail.