# accessing WCF session from aspx

Tags: c#, wcf, session-state

Is it possible to use the same session created on WCF service in a web application? any sample code to do this?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232000/how-to-use-asp-net-session-in-wcf

Comment: Can you please clarify? so WCF is on the same server as WCF? What binding using? Configuration? What session setup? Which version of IIS? Which version of .NET? Using WCF REST? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF session exists in absolutely different context - there is no relation between ASP.NET and WCF (unless you turn on AspNetCompatibility) = ASP.NET doesn't know about WCF and WCF doesn't know about ASP.NET. So if you want to share something between ASP.NET and WCF you must manually use something outside both of these technologies. It generally means some custom globally accessible (singleton) "session manager" and custom "session id" passed in each ASP.NET and WCF request.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by setting the ASPCompatibityMode but you should never do this (access ASP.NET session inside a WCF service). I would recommend you having the ASP.NET application consuming this service to simply construct a POCO object containing all the necessary information and send it to the service so that the service is not strongly coupled to this session. Accessing an ASP.NET session inside a WCF service makes this service completely non-reusable. What if you wanted to call your service from a desktop application?